# Java Soft References

Tags: java

Suppose I have three objects, A, B and C.

`A` refers to `B` with a soft reference.
`B` refers to `A` with a strong reference.
`B` also refers to `C` with a strong reference.
`C` also refers to `B` with a strong reference.
 
`C` also refers to `A` with a strong reference.

Let us assume that there are no external references to `B` or `C`. If we imagine a situation where the garbage collector decides that if it can, it will try and release memory pointed to by soft references, will `B` and `C` be released, leaving `A`? Or does some sort of circular dependency occur where the back-links from `B` and `C` to `A` somehow prevent garbage collection from happening? My understanding is that the GC should collect soft-references before OutOfMemory is thrown.

This is a highly memory intensive application that models a very large hierarchy, and as such I want the GC to discard "branches" of the hierarchy so long as there are no strong references to them. I can regenerate the branches when necessary, but that is computationally expensive, thus I implemented a cache using soft references. My general strategy is to have soft references pointing downstream (i.e. to sub-nodes of the tree) and strong references pointing back up to the parent nodes.

Comment: Yes, B and C can get GC'd, but the garbage collector is _extremely_ dumb in terms of choosing which soft references to GC.

Comment: That's fine, as long as it does do the collections eventually. To store the entire, true data model would take roughly 80GB of memory. The caching mechanism seems to be working, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: I suggest you have a small cache which is entirely strong references, and this overflows into a cache of soft/weak references.  This way, when you GC and the system has to catch up it doesn't also lose it's cache entirely (i.e. you could find almost all the soft references are cleaned up)

Comment: @PeterLawrey given the application, it would be incredibly difficult to track what hard references from this pool were actually in use. Somewhere I'd have to have a map of some kind, and based on the number of requests I'd be making to this pool (100 million+), the look up time would kill me. However, it is unlikely that ALL of the soft references would be GC'd all at once since if I have even one strong reference to an object, that section of the hierarchy tree is strongly reachable.

Comment: @bss36504 not all references will be cleaned up but it might be 99%.  You don't need to keep track of this, you can use a simple LRU with a fixed size and strong references which overflows into a cache with soft references. This ensures that the N most recently used entries caches are always retained and gives you a measure of control.

Answer (score 3):

We assume that there is an external strong reference to object `A`. (i.e. some "root" object points to `A`.)

By [definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#reachability), object `B` is softly reachable because there is no chain of strong references to reach `B`, but there is a chain that consists of strong and soft references to reach `B`. Thus `B` can be garbage collected at the JVM's discretion.

Similarly, object `C` is not strongly reachable but is softly reachable, thus it can also be garbage collected in the same manner as `B`.

Due to the definition of reaching objects from the root, the fact that `B` and `C` form a cycle makes no difference whatsoever. Java uses fully general tracing garbage collection (mark-and-sweep or copying), which is immune to reference cycles that refcount-based garbage collections suffer from.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hard references pointing back up the tree will not stop B and C from being collected.